# How do I know the status of chrome.experimental.socket?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

When I use "chrome.experimental.socket API" on chrome-extension,
how do I know the socket had been disconnected or, is disconnected just now.
I'm use Canary-Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just made a [change](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome?view=rev&revision=150190) which adds a getInfo call to the socket API, which includes the connected/disconnected state.

However it's worth noting that a socket may remain 'connected' even if say, the remote end has dropped the connection; after this kind of drop, a read() will return an error/EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the state of a socket is currently not possible with the API. I have filed a [Chromium feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=135464) for this.